# ngFor in Urtente.component.html do not show

Tags: angular, typescript, service, frontend, ngfor

Good morning ,
I don't understand why le in the users.component.html section doesn't work for me while in the "AppComponent" section, it works.

the two parts appear to be made in the usual way

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-d2tutp?file=app/utente/utente.component.html

Permessi.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class PermessiServiceService {
 public permessi: Permessi[] = [
   {
     IdSezione: '1',
     IdSottoSezione: '1',
     IdGruppo: '1',
     descSezione: 'Admin',
     descSottoSezione: 'Gestione Utenti',
   },
   {
     IdSezione: '2',
     IdSottoSezione: '2',
     IdGruppo: '1',
     descSezione: 'Sicurezza',
     descSottoSezione: 'Gestione sopralluoghi DVR',
   },
   {
     IdSezione: '2',
     IdSottoSezione: '3',
     IdGruppo: '1',
     descSezione: 'Sicurezza',
     descSottoSezione: 'Corsi',
   },
   {
     IdSezione: '3',
     IdSottoSezione: '4',
     IdGruppo: '1',
     descSezione: 'Fiscale',
     descSottoSezione: 'Gestione Appuntamenti 730',
   },
 ];

 ciccio: string[] = ['alfa', 'beta'];

 constructor() {}

 public getPermessi(): Permessi[] {
   return this.permessi;
 }

 getPermesso(index: number) {
   return this.permessi[index];
 }

 getCiccio(): string[] {
   return this.ciccio;
 }
}

export class Permessi {
 public IdSezione: string = 'aaa';
 public IdSottoSezione: string = 'aaa';
 public IdGruppo: string = 'aaa';
 public descSezione: string = 'aaa';
 public descSottoSezione: string = 'aaa';
}
```

Urtente.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let permesso of permessi">
 <p>{{ permesso }}g</p>
</div>

{{ permessi }}

<li *ngFor="let perm of permessiService.getPermessi()">
    {{ perm }}   
</li>
```

Urtente.component.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { utente } from '../models/utente';
import { UserDM } from './UserDM';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { UserLoggato } from '../utente/UserLoggato';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import {
  Permessi,
  PermessiServiceService,
} from '../Service/permessi-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'utente',
  templateUrl: './utente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./utente.component.css'],
})
export class utenteComponent implements OnInit {
  //public permessi:Permessi[]=[];
  public ciccio: string[] = [];
  constructor(public permessiService: PermessiServiceService) {}

  permessi: Permessi[] = [
    {
      IdSezione: '1',
      IdSottoSezione: '1',
      IdGruppo: '1',
      descSezione: 'Admin',
      descSottoSezione: 'Gestione Utenti',
    },
    {
      IdSezione: '2',
      IdSottoSezione: '2',
      IdGruppo: '1',
      descSezione: 'Sicurezza',
      descSottoSezione: 'Gestione sopralluoghi DVR',
    },
    {
      IdSezione: '2',
      IdSottoSezione: '3',
      IdGruppo: '1',
      descSezione: 'Sicurezza',
      descSottoSezione: 'Corsi',
    },
    {
      IdSezione: '3',
      IdSottoSezione: '4',
      IdGruppo: '1',
      descSezione: 'Fiscale',
      descSottoSezione: 'Gestione Appuntamenti 730',
    },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('OnInit');
    //      this.permessi = this.permessiService.getPermessi()
    console.log(this.permessi);
    //this.ciccio= this.permessiService.getCiccio();
  }

  @Input() UtenteLoggato: any;
}
```

Comment: There is no `users.component.html` in your example, did you mean `urtente.component.html`? Also what does `section doesn't work` mean exactly?